# How to handle JSON response using SBJSON iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-4.1

I am receiving the below response from my web service? 
Can any one has idea how to handle it using SBJSON?

```
{
"match_details" : 
    {
        "score" : 86-1
        "over" : 1.1
        "runrate" : 73.71
        "team_name" : England
        "short_name" : ENG
        "extra_run" : 50
    }

"players" : 
    {
        "key_0" : 
            {
                "is_out" : 2
                "runs" : 4
                "balls" : 2
                "four" : 1
                "six" : 0
                "batsman_name" : Ajmal Shahzad *
                "wicket_info" : not out
            }

        "key_1" : 
            {
                "is_out" : 1
                "runs" : 12
                "balls" : 6
                "four" : 2
                "six" : 0
                "batsman_name" : Andrew Strauss
                "wicket_info" : c. Kevin b.Kevin
            }

        "key_2" : 
            {
                "is_out" : 2
                "runs" : 20
                "balls" : 7
                "four" : 4
                "six" : 0
                "batsman_name" : Chris Tremlett *
                "wicket_info" : not out
            }

      }

"fow" : 
    {
        "0" : 40-1
    }

}
```

I have done something like this:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `SBJSON/JSON.h` header file and do something like this ...

```
NSString *jsonResponseString = ...your JSON response...;

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [jsonResponseString JSONValue];

NSDictionary *players = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"players"];

NSDictionary *player = [players objectForKey:@"key_0"];

NSLog( @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", [player objectForKey:@"is_out"],
  [player objectForKey:@"runs"], [player objectForKey:@"balls"],
  [player objectForKey:@"four"], [player objectForKey:@"six"],
  [player objectForKey:@"batsman_name"], [player objectForKey:@"wicket_info"] );
```

... etc.

Comment: You're welcome. Choose one answer and mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the response as an array. But the main question is: What do you want to do with your data? ;)

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSString * response = [request responseString];
NSMutableArray *array = [parser objectWithString:response error:nil];
NSMutableArray *match = [array valueForKey:@"match_details"];
NSMutableArray *players = [array valueForKey:@"players"];

// This should display your players name
for(id player in players) {
   NSLog(@"Player name: %@", [(NSDictionary *)player valueForKey:@"batsman_name"]);
}
```